# What is the conventional type for representing boolean values in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file-io, types

I'm reading binary data from a file, the particular value in question is a `uchar` (unsigned 1-byte value) and conceptually is boolean.  How do I write the `fread` statement?

I.e. what should I put in for `???` in the following:

```
is_valid=fread(fid, 1, 'uint8=>???','a');
```

I figure that I could use `'*uint8'` for the conversion string, but I'd like for the result type to be most-like what other users would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Booleans in MATLAB are represented by the [`logical`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/overview-of-the-logical-class.html) type. However, `fread` doesn't support reading logicals, so read them as `uint8` and convert to `logical` later. For instance:

```
is_valid = logical(fread(fid, 1, 'uint8', 'a'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on 2012b:

```
A = fread(fid, 1, 'uint8=>logical');
```